How can I get advanced team stats from the NBA API?
I'm trying to gather data so I can make a database using Google Sheets and I want to get advanced stats but I haven't been able to get them in any way I've tried so far. The ones I need the most are offensive ratings, defensive ratings, pace, and net ratings (basketball).
The below is my code. Sorry if it's a bit rough around the edges, a lot of it was influenced from multiple different sources.
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import leaguegamefinder
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import pandas as pd
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

# Load credentials from JSON key file
creds = ****]
)

# Initialize Sheets API
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# Define your spreadsheet ID and range
SPREADSHEET_ID = 'sheet id'
RANGE_NAME = 'planilhanba!A2:ZZZ'

@app.route('/api/jogos/all_teams', methods=['GET'])
def obter_jogos_todos_times():
    # Get games for all teams in the 2024-25 season using nba_api
    gamefinder = leaguegamefinder.LeagueGameFinder(
        season_nullable='2024-25'
    )
    games = gamefinder.get_data_frames()[0]

    # Select specific columns for detailed statistics
    columns_to_include = [
        "TEAM_ID", "TEAM_NAME", "GAME_ID", "GAME_DATE", "MATCHUP", "WL",
        "PTS", "REB", "OREB", "DREB", "AST", "STL", "BLK", "TOV", "PF",
        "PLUS_MINUS", "FGM", "FGA", "FG_PCT", "FG3M", "FG3A", "FG3_PCT",
        "FTM", "FTA", "FT_PCT", "MIN", "TEAM_ABBREVIATION", "SEASON_ID"
    ]
    games = games[columns_to_include]

    # Remove exact duplicate rows
    games = games.drop_duplicates()

    # Ensure numeric columns are of the right type
    numeric_columns = [
        "PTS", "REB", "OREB", "DREB", "AST", "STL", "BLK", "TOV", "PF",
        "PLUS_MINUS", "FGM", "FGA", "FG3M", "FG3A", "FTM", "FTA", "MIN"
    ]
    for col in numeric_columns:
        games[col] = pd.to_numeric(games[col], errors='coerce')

    # Create additional columns for home and away points
    games['HOME_PTS'] = games.apply(lambda x: x['PTS'] if 'vs' in x['MATCHUP'] else 0, axis=1)
    games['AWAY_PTS'] = games.apply(lambda x: x['PTS'] if 'vs' not in x['MATCHUP'] else 0, axis=1)

    # Group by GAME_ID to combine home and away statistics
    games_grouped = games.groupby('GAME_ID').agg({
        'GAME_DATE': 'first',
        'MATCHUP': 'first',
        'WL': 'first',
        'HOME_PTS': 'sum',
        'AWAY_PTS': 'sum',
        'PTS': 'sum',
        'PLUS_MINUS': 'sum',
        'FGM': 'sum',
        'FGA': 'sum',
        'FG_PCT': 'mean',
        'FG3M': 'sum',
        'FG3A': 'sum',
        'FG3_PCT': 'mean',
        'FTM': 'sum',
        'FTA': 'sum',
        'FT_PCT': 'mean',
        'SEASON_ID': 'first'
    }).reset_index()

    # Replace NaN values with empty strings for Sheets compatibility
    games_grouped = games_grouped.fillna('')

    # Convert DataFrame to dictionary format for Google Sheets
    values = games_grouped.to_dict(orient="records")

    body = {
        'values': [list(item.values()) for item in values]
    }

    try:
        service.spreadsheets().values().update(
            spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
            range=RANGE_NAME,
            valueInputOption='RAW',
            body=body
        ).execute()
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 400

    return jsonify(values)

def get_team_ratings():
    # URL for team stats from Basketball Reference
    url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2025.html'
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    tables = pd.read_html(response.text)

    # Ensure we have at least two tables for Eastern and Western conferences
    if len(tables) < 2:
        return pd.DataFrame()

    # Extract Eastern and Western Conference data
    eastern_conference = tables[0]
    western_conference = tables[1]

    # Clean and rename columns for Eastern Conference
    eastern_conference.columns = ['TEAM_NAME', 'W', 'L', 'W/L%', 'GB', 'PS/G', 'PA/G', 'SRS']
    eastern_conference['CONFERENCE'] = 'Eastern'

    # Clean and rename columns for Western Conference
    western_conference.columns = ['TEAM_NAME', 'W', 'L', 'W/L%', 'GB', 'PS/G', 'PA/G', 'SRS']
    western_conference['CONFERENCE'] = 'Western'

    # Combine both DataFrames
    combined_stats = pd.concat([eastern_conference, western_conference], ignore_index=True)

    # Select relevant columns for output
    combined_stats = combined_stats[['TEAM_NAME', 'W', 'L', 'W/L%', 'PS/G', 'PA/G', 'CONFERENCE']]

    # Replace NaN values with empty strings for Sheets compatibility
    combined_stats = combined_stats.fillna('')

    return combined_stats

@app.route('/api/team_ratings', methods=['GET'])
def obter_team_ratings():
    team_ratings = get_team_ratings()

    if team_ratings.empty:
        return jsonify({"error": "No team ratings found."}), 404

    values = team_ratings.to_dict(orient="records")

    body = {
        'values': [list(item.values()) for item in values]
    }

    try:
        service.spreadsheets().values().update(
            spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
            range='planilhanba!S2:DDD',
            valueInputOption='RAW',
            body=body
        ).execute()
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 400

    return jsonify(values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)



Here is an image of the data I have been able to compile so far. I have also tried using the basketball reference API but it didn't help much.

To get the data from basketball-reference.com, looking at the source html, you will see some of the tables are within the comments. You need to either use Beautfulsoup to iterate through the Comments, or simply remove the comment tags, then parse the table(s)
Code:
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2025.html'
response = requests.get(url)

html = response.text.replace('<--','').replace('-->','')
table = pd.read_html(response.text, attrs={'id':'advanced-team'}, header=1)[0]

Output:
print(table.to_string())
      Rk                    Team   Age    W    L  PW  PL    MOV   SOS    SRS   ORtg   DRtg  NRtg   Pace    FTr   3PAr    TS%  Unnamed: 17   eFG%  TOV%  ORB%  FT/FGA  Unnamed: 22  eFG%.1  TOV%.1  DRB%  FT/FGA.1  Unnamed: 27                       Arena  Attend.  Attend./G
0    1.0   Golden State Warriors  27.5  4.0  1.0   5   0  20.40 -0.75  19.65  119.4   99.1  20.3  100.3  0.178  0.478  0.590          NaN  0.569  13.0  31.0   0.134          NaN   0.465    16.5  71.2     0.205          NaN                Chase Center    54192      18064
1    2.0     Cleveland Cavaliers  26.8  5.0  0.0   4   1  18.20 -0.98  17.22  124.1  106.1  18.0  101.2  0.264  0.413  0.645          NaN  0.624  12.4  20.9   0.193          NaN   0.503    16.0  73.5     0.242          NaN  Rocket Mortgage Fieldhouse    38864      19432
2    3.0   Oklahoma City Thunder  24.1  4.0  0.0   4   0  17.50 -3.45  14.05  108.2   91.3  16.9  103.8  0.187  0.407  0.537          NaN  0.512   9.9  19.1   0.140          NaN   0.437    17.3  72.0     0.161          NaN               Paycom Center    35339      17670
3    4.0          Boston Celtics  29.1  4.0  1.0   4   1  11.40 -3.55   7.85  124.0  112.8  11.2   99.4  0.244  0.548  0.603          NaN  0.568   9.7  25.4   0.200          NaN   0.540    13.6  76.6     0.199          NaN                   TD Garden    38312      19156
4    5.0        Sacramento Kings  27.9  2.0  2.0   3   1   6.00 -1.06   4.94  115.5  109.6   5.9  100.8  0.289  0.405  0.603          NaN  0.560  11.7  17.0   0.239          NaN   0.529    15.5  75.4     0.206          NaN             Golden 1 Center    34475      17238
5    6.0           Orlando Magic  24.8  3.0  2.0   3   2   4.40 -5.74  -1.34  112.8  108.4   4.4   99.5  0.330  0.501  0.574          NaN  0.534  13.0  23.3   0.246          NaN   0.525    13.7  78.6     0.225          NaN                  Kia Center    37933      18967
6    7.0         Houston Rockets  24.4  2.0  2.0   3   1   4.25 -5.00  -0.75  112.8  108.5   4.3   98.7  0.267  0.434  0.527          NaN  0.484  10.6  29.9   0.209          NaN   0.507    15.2  68.9     0.237          NaN               Toyota Center    36110      18055
7    8.0        Dallas Mavericks  27.3  3.0  1.0   2   2   3.25 -1.25   2.00  114.5  111.2   3.3   98.7  0.198  0.426  0.543          NaN  0.513   9.4  27.0   0.154          NaN   0.524    14.4  74.6     0.263          NaN    American Airlines Center    40184      20092
8    9.0            Phoenix Suns  30.2  3.0  1.0   2   2   3.00  6.00   9.00  112.7  109.7   3.0   98.4  0.330  0.459  0.607          NaN  0.564  14.0  15.3   0.263          NaN   0.516    12.3  77.4     0.220          NaN            Footprint Center    34142      17071
9   10.0    Los Angeles Clippers  29.5  2.0  2.0   2   2   2.25  7.21   9.46  108.7  106.4   2.3   98.4  0.260  0.367  0.556          NaN  0.527  15.3  27.7   0.186          NaN   0.523    14.6  77.9     0.200          NaN                 Intuit Dome    35027      17514
10  11.0         New York Knicks  27.4  2.0  2.0   2   2   1.25  3.52   4.77  120.6  119.2   1.4   93.7  0.249  0.374  0.610          NaN  0.575  12.1  23.5   0.204          NaN   0.573    10.5  77.8     0.164          NaN  Madison Square Garden (IV)    39624      19812
11  12.0           Brooklyn Nets  26.4  2.0  3.0   3   2   0.40 -5.26  -4.86  117.0  116.6   0.4   98.8  0.274  0.494  0.597          NaN  0.556  13.6  22.4   0.227          NaN   0.558    13.3  77.5     0.358          NaN             Barclays Center    35852      17926
12  13.0  Minnesota Timberwolves  28.2  2.0  2.0   2   2   0.00  1.18   1.18  113.8  113.8   0.0   98.0  0.290  0.505  0.597          NaN  0.565  15.0  23.0   0.218          NaN   0.519    10.3  75.7     0.200          NaN               Target Center    37956      18978
13  14.0       Charlotte Hornets  26.4  2.0  2.0   2   2  -0.75 -5.12  -5.87  118.8  119.5  -0.7   99.8  0.277  0.484  0.580          NaN  0.543  14.8  36.1   0.217          NaN   0.537    10.8  72.2     0.247          NaN             Spectrum Center    32215      16108
14  15.0      Los Angeles Lakers  28.3  3.0  2.0   2   3  -2.00  8.27   6.27  115.1  117.1  -2.0  100.6  0.321  0.349  0.586          NaN  0.539  12.7  24.0   0.259          NaN   0.580    12.7  81.3     0.182          NaN            Crypto.com Arena    56991      18997
15  16.0           Chicago Bulls  25.7  3.0  2.0   2   3  -2.80 -1.15  -3.95  106.3  108.9  -2.6  106.7  0.245  0.483  0.559          NaN  0.531  13.8  19.9   0.177          NaN   0.510     9.9  81.3     0.156          NaN               United Center    39938      19969
16  17.0              Miami Heat  27.7  2.0  2.0   2   2  -3.00 -1.72  -4.72  111.1  114.2  -3.1   95.4  0.300  0.460  0.556          NaN  0.521  11.0  21.8   0.217          NaN   0.521    13.6  68.4     0.176          NaN               Kaseya Center    58876      19625
17  18.0          Denver Nuggets  27.0  2.0  2.0   2   2  -3.25  2.54  -0.71  112.8  116.0  -3.2   97.3  0.311  0.324  0.549          NaN  0.499  10.1  26.8   0.251          NaN   0.531    11.1  73.8     0.162          NaN                  Ball Arena    39477      19739
18  19.0       Memphis Grizzlies  25.0  2.0  3.0   2   3  -4.20 -4.70  -8.90  112.8  116.8  -4.0  104.1  0.291  0.385  0.566          NaN  0.537  13.6  27.0   0.202          NaN   0.551    13.8  70.3     0.249          NaN                 FedEx Forum    48460      16153
19  20.0         Detroit Pistons  25.9  1.0  4.0   2   3  -4.40 -0.04  -4.44  110.2  114.8  -4.6   96.3  0.249  0.418  0.562          NaN  0.522  15.2  28.2   0.202          NaN   0.537    11.0  79.5     0.237          NaN        Little Caesars Arena    39373      19687
20  21.0          Indiana Pacers  25.7  2.0  3.0   2   3  -4.80 -1.48  -6.28  112.0  116.7  -4.7   98.9  0.301  0.362  0.576          NaN  0.542  14.2  25.2   0.222          NaN   0.517    12.4  68.4     0.266          NaN       Gainbridge Fieldhouse    34548      17274
21  22.0         Milwaukee Bucks  30.4  1.0  3.0   1   3  -5.00 -3.80  -8.80  112.1  117.0  -4.9  101.7  0.359  0.429  0.599          NaN  0.555  14.4  18.3   0.277          NaN   0.539    10.0  77.9     0.202          NaN                Fiserv Forum    17790      17790
22  23.0  Portland Trail Blazers  24.4  2.0  3.0   2   3  -5.60  6.50   0.90  107.1  112.6  -5.5  100.1  0.276  0.358  0.531          NaN  0.486  14.4  29.4   0.220          NaN   0.533    13.8  72.4     0.221          NaN                 Moda Center    51808      17269
23  24.0      Washington Wizards  23.5  2.0  2.0   1   3  -6.00  3.00  -3.00  112.8  118.5  -5.7  104.6  0.262  0.435  0.572          NaN  0.528  13.4  24.0   0.219          NaN   0.576    13.6  75.0     0.249          NaN           Capital One Arena    48021      16007
24  25.0           Atlanta Hawks  24.6  2.0  3.0   2   3  -6.00 -0.54  -6.54  113.6  119.4  -5.8  103.5  0.397  0.411  0.585          NaN  0.533  14.2  25.1   0.308          NaN   0.559    13.6  72.6     0.240          NaN            State Farm Arena    46547      15516
25  26.0       San Antonio Spurs  25.5  1.0  3.0   1   3  -6.25  3.64  -2.61  105.4  111.8  -6.4   97.7  0.255  0.371  0.550          NaN  0.507  16.7  29.7   0.208          NaN   0.511    10.5  77.7     0.166          NaN           Frost Bank Center    36234      18117
26  27.0      Philadelphia 76ers  28.8  1.0  3.0   1   3  -7.25 -7.00 -14.25  107.4  114.7  -7.3   97.3  0.396  0.370  0.520          NaN  0.464  11.8  28.1   0.293          NaN   0.560    17.2  71.5     0.321          NaN          Wells Fargo Center    39513      19757
27  28.0         Toronto Raptors  24.8  1.0  4.0   1   4  -8.00 -0.49  -8.49  113.2  121.0  -7.8  100.4  0.308  0.323  0.565          NaN  0.523  15.6  35.0   0.237          NaN   0.569    12.7  73.8     0.284          NaN            Scotiabank Arena    57227      19076
28  29.0    New Orleans Pelicans  26.4  2.0  3.0   1   4  -8.20  7.43  -0.77  106.2  114.5  -8.3   99.0  0.276  0.359  0.539          NaN  0.503  14.4  27.6   0.202          NaN   0.540    13.7  70.9     0.172          NaN        Smoothie King Center    18581      18581
29  30.0               Utah Jazz  25.0  0.0  4.0   0   4 -17.00  4.42 -12.58  100.3  117.0 -16.7  101.7  0.318  0.422  0.500          NaN  0.446  14.8  27.4   0.249          NaN   0.555    11.5  70.8     0.130          NaN                Delta Center    54525      18175
30   NaN          League Average  26.6  NaN  NaN   2   2   0.00  0.00   0.00  112.8  112.8   NaN   99.9  0.282  0.419  0.570          NaN  0.532  13.2  25.5   0.218          NaN   0.532    13.2  74.5     0.218          NaN                         NaN    40604      18181


Through the nba api, you need the endpoint leaguedashteamstats
Code
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import leaguedashteamstats

advancedGamefinder = leaguedashteamstats.LeagueDashTeamStats(
    season='2024-25'
    )

advancedGames = advancedGamefinder.get_data_frames()[0]

Output:
print(advancedGames.to_string())
       TEAM_ID               TEAM_NAME  GP  W  L  W_PCT    MIN  FGM  FGA  FG_PCT  FG3M  FG3A  FG3_PCT  FTM  FTA  FT_PCT  OREB  DREB  REB  AST   TOV  STL  BLK  BLKA   PF  PFD  PTS  PLUS_MINUS  GP_RANK  W_RANK  L_RANK  W_PCT_RANK  MIN_RANK  FGM_RANK  FGA_RANK  FG_PCT_RANK  FG3M_RANK  FG3A_RANK  FG3_PCT_RANK  FTM_RANK  FTA_RANK  FT_PCT_RANK  OREB_RANK  DREB_RANK  REB_RANK  AST_RANK  TOV_RANK  STL_RANK  BLK_RANK  BLKA_RANK  PF_RANK  PFD_RANK  PTS_RANK  PLUS_MINUS_RANK
0   1610612737           Atlanta Hawks   5  2  3   0.40  240.0  198  428   0.463    60   176    0.341  132  170   0.776    54   159  213  134  83.0   52   31    30  112  129  588       -30.0        2      12      18          19         8        13        17           13         14         14            20         1         1           14         15         14        16         9        22         4         9         21       22         2         6               26
1   1610612738          Boston Celtics   5  4  1   0.80  245.0  215  471   0.456   105   258    0.407   94  115   0.817    58   157  215  120  56.0   39   22    27   87  103  629        57.0        2       2       3           3         3         4         3           15          1          1             2        14        15            5         13         18        15        16         8        15        19         19       10        14         2                4
2   1610612751           Brooklyn Nets   5  2  3   0.40  245.0  204  441   0.463    82   218    0.376  100  121   0.826    47   155  202  130  78.0   38   20    26  146   99  590         2.0        2      12      18          19         3        10        11           14          4          4             9         9        13            3         21         21        20        11        19        16        24         18       29        17         5               12
3   1610612766       Charlotte Hornets   4  2  2   0.50  192.0  163  364   0.448    69   176    0.392   79  101   0.782    66   127  193   93  71.0   28   27    24   97   90  474        -3.0       22      12       6          11        24        26        25           18          9         14             6        24        22           13          7         27        22        28        13        27        14         16       14        21        22               15
4   1610612741           Chicago Bulls   5  3  2   0.60  240.0  201  458   0.439    84   221    0.380   81  112   0.723    49   209  258  138  81.0   31   16    35   83   89  567       -14.0        2       6       6           6         8        11         6           24          3          3             8        22        19           28         20          2         2         6        20        25        27         26        7        22        11               20
5   1610612739     Cleveland Cavaliers   5  5  0   1.00  240.0  235  436   0.539    74   180    0.411   84  115   0.730    39   161  200  142  69.0   60   30    23  110   99  628        91.0        2       1       1           1         8         2        13            1          6         12             1        19        15           27         24         12        21         5        12         1        11         12       21        17         3                2
6   1610612742        Dallas Mavericks   5  3  2   0.60  240.0  206  468   0.440    69   193    0.358   73   96   0.760    64   159  223  122  53.0   42   28    20  120   92  554         7.0        2       6       6           6         8         9         5           23          9          8            14        25        26           17          9         14        12        14         6        10        13          6       26        20        15                9
7   1610612743          Denver Nuggets   4  2  2   0.50  202.0  163  370   0.441    43   120    0.358   93  115   0.809    51   138  189  109  47.0   33   21    31   76   98  462       -13.0       22      12       6          11        22        26        23           22         29         30            13        15        15            7         18         23        23        18         2        21        22         22        4        19        25               19
8   1610612765         Detroit Pistons   5  1  4   0.20  240.0  190  426   0.446    65   178    0.365   86  106   0.811    60   167  227  111  85.0   23   25    25  109   89  531       -22.0        2      26      27          27         8        19        19           20         13         13            12        18        21            6         11         10        10        17        24        28        16         17       20        22        18               21
9   1610612744   Golden State Warriors   5  4  1   0.80  240.0  224  471   0.476    88   225    0.391   63   84   0.750    72   168  240  158  76.0   58   34    23  116   84  599       102.0        2       2       3           3         8         3         3            8          2          2             7        29        28           18          3          9         4         2        18         2         5         12       24        25         4                1
10  1610612745         Houston Rockets   5  3  2   0.60  240.0  194  475   0.408    66   198    0.333   99  128   0.773    78   156  234  101  60.0   38   17    38  117  112  553        23.0        2       6       6           6         8        15         2           29         11          7            21        10        11           15          1         19         7        26         9        16        26         28       25         9        16                6
11  1610612754          Indiana Pacers   5  2  3   0.40  250.0  213  442   0.482    53   160    0.331   98  133   0.737    54   156  210  146  83.0   43   27    21  127  109  577       -24.0        2      12      18          19         2         5        10            5         21         21            23        13         9           23         15         19        18         3        22         9        14          7       27        11        10               22
12  1610612746             LA Clippers   5  2  3   0.40  245.0  210  447   0.470    55   165    0.333   83  113   0.735    66   174  240  137  85.0   42   21    28  115  105  558         3.0        2      12      18          19         3         7         9           11         18         18            21        20        18           24          7          6         4         7        24        10        22         20       23        13        13               11
13  1610612747      Los Angeles Lakers   5  3  2   0.60  240.0  207  433   0.478    53   151    0.351  112  139   0.806    50   161  211  133  72.0   36   22    23   85  115  579       -10.0        2       6       6           6         8         8        15            6         21         25            15         3         4            9         19         12        17        10        14        18        19         12        9         7         9               17
14  1610612763       Memphis Grizzlies   6  3  3   0.50  288.0  259  542   0.478    70   205    0.341  121  165   0.733    70   210  280  180  99.0   45   33    31  147  143  709         2.0        1       6      18          11         1         1         1            7          8          6            19         2         2           25          4          1         1         1        30         6         6         22       30         1         1               12
15  1610612748              Miami Heat   4  2  2   0.50  192.0  147  337   0.436    57   155    0.368   73  101   0.723    39   128  167  108  47.0   33   20    23   69   80  424       -12.0       22      12       6          11        24        29        28           26         16         24            10        25        22           29         24         26        27        20         2        21        24         12        2        28        30               18
16  1610612749         Milwaukee Bucks   5  1  4   0.20  240.0  200  425   0.471    56   183    0.306   99  137   0.723    40   177  217  109  74.0   33   25    17  105  110  555       -43.0        2      26      27          27         8        12        20           10         17         10            28        10         7           30         23          4        14        18        17        21        16          3       16        10        14               29
17  1610612750  Minnesota Timberwolves   4  2  2   0.50  192.0  154  331   0.465    66   167    0.395   72   96   0.750    38   134  172  103  66.0   21   13    16   82   83  446         0.0       22      12       6          11        24        28        30           12         11         17             5        27        26           18         26         24        25        25        11        30        30          2        5        26        28               14
18  1610612740    New Orleans Pelicans   5  2  3   0.40  240.0  192  435   0.441    54   156    0.346   88  120   0.733    60   158  218  125  82.0   47   38    39   91  101  526       -41.0        2      12      18          19         8        16        14           21         19         23            16        16        14           25         11         16        13        13        21         5         1         29       13        16        19               28
19  1610612752         New York Knicks   4  2  2   0.50  192.0  167  334   0.500    50   125    0.400   68   83   0.819    36   126  162   91  51.0   23   14    17   67   76  452         5.0       22      12       6          11        24        24        29            2         24         29             3        28        29            4         28         28        29        29         4        28        29          3        1        29        26               10
20  1610612760   Oklahoma City Thunder   4  4  0   1.00  192.0  173  386   0.448    49   157    0.312   54   72   0.750    38   149  187   98  46.0   55   36    19   71   62  449        70.0       22       2       1           1        24        21        22           17         26         22            27        30        30           18         26         22        24        27         1         3         2          5        3        30        27                3
21  1610612753           Orlando Magic   5  3  2   0.60  240.0  191  427   0.447    74   214    0.346  105  141   0.745    52   173  225  128  73.0   44   35    22  104  118  561        22.0        2       6       6           6         8        18        18           19          6          5            17         7         3           21         17          7        11        12        15         7         3          8       15         4        12                7
22  1610612755      Philadelphia 76ers   4  1  3   0.25  197.0  145  351   0.413    36   130    0.277  103  139   0.741    55   113  168   69  55.0   31   15    31  107  108  429       -29.0       22      26      18          26        23        30        26           28         30         28            29         8         4           22         14         30        26        30         7        25        28         22       18        12        29               25
23  1610612756            Phoenix Suns   5  4  1   0.80  245.0  198  409   0.484    75   189    0.397  109  136   0.801    33   175  208  136  73.0   42   32    22  108  116  580        18.0        2       2       3           3         3        13        21            4          5          9             4         4         8           10         29          5        19         8        15        10         8          8       19         6         7                8
24  1610612757  Portland Trail Blazers   5  2  3   0.40  240.0  192  450   0.427    53   161    0.329   99  124   0.798    69   165  234  108  85.0   40   33    32  105  117  536       -28.0        2      12      18          19         8        16         8           27         21         19            24        10        12           11          6         11         7        20        24        14         6         25       16         5        17               24
25  1610612758        Sacramento Kings   4  2  2   0.50  192.0  168  343   0.490    48   139    0.345   82   99   0.828    27   132  159  104  51.0   36   22    13   83   81  466        24.0       22      12       6          11        24        23        27            3         27         27            18        21        24            2         30         25        30        24         4        18        19          1        7        27        24                5
26  1610612759       San Antonio Spurs   5  2  3   0.40  240.0  188  429   0.438    54   168    0.321   88  109   0.807    63   181  244  122  86.0   41   31    22   82  102  518        -7.0        2      12      18          19         8        20        16           25         19         16            26        16        20            8         10          3         3        14        27        13         9          8        5        15        20               16
27  1610612761         Toronto Raptors   5  1  4   0.20  245.0  213  452   0.471    47   146    0.322  107  139   0.770    75   158  233  146  95.0   44   35    36  132  114  580       -40.0        2      26      27          27         3         5         7            9         28         26            25         5         4           16          2         16         9         3        28         7         3         27       28         8         7               27
28  1610612762               Utah Jazz   5  0  5   0.00  240.0  170  440   0.386    50   183    0.273  106  133   0.797    70   169  239  106  97.0   35   29    39   87  119  496       -86.0        2      30      30          30         8        22        12           30         24         10            30         6         9           12          4          8         6        23        29        20        12         29       10         3        21               30
29  1610612764      Washington Wizards   4  2  2   0.50  192.0  166  370   0.449    59   161    0.366   81   97   0.835    43   123  166  108  64.0   32   23    22   90   87  472       -24.0       22      12       6          11        24        25        23           16         15         19            11        22        25            1         22         29        28        20        10        24        18          8       12        24        23               22

